# Table scraping from website with BeautifulSoup 4.8.2

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table from a website, but it does not quite work. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and bs4 4.8.2. Also, I'm not proficient in HTML so excuse me if I get some of the terminology wrong.

I'm trying to scrape the table class that is under the parent class with "id = 'track_1_box'" which can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qInNw.png). The information I'm trying to extract are the strings "title = 'Canada'" and "Cole" but right now I can't even access the table.

This is what I've attempted so far.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

#%%
url = 'https://www.mkleaderboards.com/mkw/charts/world/nonsc/12'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", class_='table')
```

However, the 'table' variable returns an empty list. I have also tried to access the parent class with

```
soup.find_all(class_ = 'panel inline_box track_box')
```

which returns

```
[<div class="panel inline_box track_box" id="track_1_box">
 </div>, <div class="panel inline_box track_box" id="track_2_box">
 </div>, <div class="panel inline_box track_box" id="track_3_box">
 </div>, <div class="panel inline_box track_box" id="track_4_box">
 </div>]
```

but not what's "inside" the four div classes.

Am I doing something wrong or is there something with the website that is preventing me from scraping the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded via JavaScript, but you can use `requests` module to get the data:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.mkleaderboards.com/mkw/charts/world/nonsc/12'
api_url = 'https://www.mkleaderboards.com/api/charts/mkw_nonsc_world/{num}'

cup_id = int(url.split('/')[-1])

# box 1:
box1 = requests.get(api_url.format(num=cup_id*4+1)).json()
# box 2:
box2 = requests.get(api_url.format(num=cup_id*4+2)).json()
# box 3:
box3 = requests.get(api_url.format(num=cup_id*4+3)).json()
# box 4:
box4 = requests.get(api_url.format(num=cup_id*4+4)).json()

# uncomment this to print data to screen:
# print(json.dumps(box1, indent=4))
# print(json.dumps(box2, indent=4))
# print(json.dumps(box3, indent=4))
# print(json.dumps(box4, indent=4))

# print box1 to screen:
for d in box1['data']:
    print('{:<30} {:<20} {}'.format(d['name'], d['country_name'], d['score_formatted']))
```

Prints:

```
Cole                           Canada               1:08.774
Kasey                          United States        1:08.881
SwareJonge                     Netherlands          1:09.036
Sosis                          United States        1:09.050
Paul M.                        United States        1:09.066
Sword                          United Kingdom       1:09.118
Gustav                         Sweden               1:09.136
Guy                            United States        1:09.143
Glaceon                        Japan                1:09.157
Liam [MKW]                     United Kingdom       1:09.171
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Could you explain how to identify that the data is loaded via JavaScript?

Comment: @fnehfneh When you do `print(soup)` and don't see the required information there, there's big change the data is loaded via JavaScript. Next step is to check Firefox/Chrome network tab for the requests the page is making to load the data.

Comment: Thank you once again. :)